# How do I update information in my datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I need to check if the item is in datastore before I update it.

I have 2 lists: `UNIQUES = ["B","K","V"]` and `COUNTS = [5, 10, 3]`

This is the model:

```
class Rep(db.Model):
    mAUTHOR = db.UserProperty(auto_current_user=True)
    mUNIQUE = db.TextProperty()
    mCOUNT = db.IntegerProperty()
    mDATE = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

This function updates the database:

```
def write_to_db(S, C):
    REP = Rep(mUNIQUE=S, mCOUNT=C)
    db.put(REP)
```

Inspired by this [page](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/commontasks.html#update) I try:

```
for i in range(len(UNIQUES)):            
    C_QUERY = Rep.all()
    C_QUERY.filter("mAUTHOR =", user)
    C_QUERY.filter("mUNIQUE =", UNIQUES[i])
    C_RESULT = C_QUERY.fetch(1)
    if C_RESULT:
        C = C_RESULT.mCOUNT + COUNTS[i]
        S = db.Text(UNIQUES[i])
        write_to_db(S,C)
    else:
        C = COUNTS[i]
        S = UNIQUES[i]
        write_to_db(S, C)
```

But the result is not what I expect. C_RESULT is always empty; and instead of updating, a new record is created. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

**EDIT3: Problem solved**

As per David Underhill's comment I updated the code and it now works.

```
        if C_RESULT:
            rep=C_RESULT[0]
            rep.mCOUNT+=COUNTS[i]
            rep.put()
```

**EDIT2: Related question**

How do I update this query and put it back with updated information?

```
C_QUERY = Rep.all()
C_QUERY.filter("mAUTHOR =", user)
C_QUERY.filter("mUNIQUE =", UNIQUES[i])
C_RESULT = C_QUERY.fetch(1)
```

I want to change mCOUNT and then write it to datastore. How do I this? This looks like the exact same thing they do in [this page](http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/commontasks.html#update) but I could not make it work. Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

I updated the code per David Underhill's answer. That solved the problem (but the functionality is not right. I am not sure if that should be a different question).

```
    for i in range(len(UNIQUES)):                        
        C_QUERY = Rep.all()
        C_QUERY.filter("mAUTHOR =", user)
        C_QUERY.filter("mUNIQUE =", UNIQUES[i])
        C_RESULT = C_QUERY.fetch(1)                
        if C_RESULT:
            C = C_RESULT[0].mCOUNT + COUNTS[i]
            S = UNIQUES[i]
            write_to_db(S, C)
        else:
            C = COUNTS[i]
            S = UNIQUES[i]
            write_to_db(S, C)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the query is trying to filter `mUNIQUE`.  However, you declared `mUNIQUE` as a [`db.TextProperty`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#TextProperty) which is *never* indexed.  As a result, you query never finds any results.

**Solution**: Change `mUNIQUE` to a [`db.StringProperty`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#StringProperty) (which *is* indexed by default).

You should also consider updating `Rep` in a [transaction](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions.html) - the current code may fail to property add `COUNTS[i]` if two requests try to update the same entity concurrently.

Also, you can update `S = db.Text(UNIQUES[i])` to simply `S = UNIQUES[i]`.

Comment: @David Underhill: Many thanks! That solved the problem. I added the updated code above. Can you also suggest any solutions about how to fix the rest of the code. How do I update just this item? The way it is now it updates the whole database; so there is always 1 item in it. (sorry I am still very confused about dot notation and what object is what) Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm not sure what you mean by "this" in "How do I update just this item?"  Perhaps you could provide more details about what you're trying to accomplish (here is fine; in another question might be better).

Comment: @David Underhill: thanks. I started a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119560/updating-just-1-entity-in-datastore

Comment: Sorry I am deleting that question.

Comment: I added the new question above.

Comment: Another problem - your update code actually creates a brand new `Rep` entity each time.  Instead, of calling your `write_to_db` function, just do something like this:  `rep=C_RESULT[0];rep.mCOUNT+=COUNTS[i];rep.put()` (and in a transaction).